# Changing date format returns NA

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with the Date column as:

```
Date
-------------
Aug. 21, 2022
Aug. 19, 2022
Aug. 18, 2022
...
Aug. 22, 2017
```

And I need the format to be in typical Date syntax i.e %d-%m-%y. However when I run the code

```
ftse$Date <- as.Date('Aug. 21, 2022', format = '%b-%d-%y')
ftse$Date <- format(ftse$Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

I get a column of NAs. My guess would be that the mix of a hyphen and full stop don't agree with the format function. Does anyone have any idea how to change?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Another typo is that 4-digit year should be `%Y` with an uppercase `Y`. Lower case `%y` is for 2-digit year

Comment: Learn something new every day! Thanks @benson23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

completing akrun's answer:

```
install.packages("parsedate")
library(parsedate)
ftse$Date<-as.Date(parse_date(ftse$Date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format is slightly different than the one you indicate. Since you have a dot and a comma, you have to include them in the `format` string. As mentioned in the comments, you also need to set `%Y` (4-digit year) instead of `%y` (2-digit year).

```r
as.Date('Aug. 21, 2022', format = '%b. %d, %Y')
#[1] "2022-08-21"

format(as.Date('Aug. 21, 2022', format = '%b. %d, %Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')
#[1] "21-08-2022"
```

Comment: Fantastic, I wasn't aware that the format string was able to take punctuation in this manner. Far simpler than I thought! Thank you